# Cannot connect to SQL Server when run VS with specific user

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2014

I have 2 projects in the same solution. Both of them referencing to 4.6.1 .NET Framework and one project **can** connect to a database and another **cannot** connect to the **same** database. I use the same connection string for both projects. I start Visual Studio 2019 (`v 16.2.1`) with specific credentials in order to be able to connect to that db. This is how I create connection:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=Database;server=servername;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=300");
conn.Open();
```

This is the error message I get from the project I can't connect with:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'username'.'
```

Username there is not the username I've started Visual Studio with for some reason.

There is only one difference in those projects is `SqlConnection` instance.

So the instance which succeeds to connect to db comes from here:

```
// Type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
// Assembly: System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// MVID: 50EC765D-C933-47F6-BBBB-DAE3EBBBADF0
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll
```

And `SqlConnection` which cannot connect to the db comes from here:

```
// Type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
// Assembly: System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// MVID: 7D5B9D5B-F184-427C-87AE-38EC6FDCF483
// Assembly location: C:\Users\usr\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.4.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Data.SqlClient.dll
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change the reference for the broken project because I have other packages dependent on that instance.

Comment: _"Username there is not the username I've started Visual Studio with for some reason"_ - that sounds like your problem, rather than the assembly differences. Is the username your own login? What do `Environment.UserName` and `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` return in VS?

Comment: @stuartd in both projects it returns the same user. And that is my Windows user I logged in with. But to access db, I need another user, the user I start VS with

Comment: @stuartd could be that it is related where it reads binary from? As you can see the binary is located at `C:\Users\usr\...`

Comment: Would using [impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=netframework-4.8) to access the DB an option? You could store the password in an environment variable so it isn't i the code.